# C Array with Pointer to Struct Inside a Struct

Tags: c++, c, data-structures, flatbuffers

I'm implementing the below struct which consist of some parameters and also an array of struct pointer. However when I try to insert an item to array it gave an error such as free() invalid pointer on a meaningless line.

```
typedef struct {
    ResponseTypes responseTypes;
    bool status;
    unsigned int statusCode;
}BaseResponse;

typedef struct {
    BaseResponse baseResponse;
    unsigned long orderId;
    const char* passThrough;
    const char* orderToken;
    unsigned int orderBookId;
    unsigned long quantity;
    int price;
    const char* account;
    StrategyType strategy;
    const char* strategyIdentifier;
    unsigned long preTradeQuantity;
    Side side;
    unsigned long long timestamp;
}OrderAccepted;

typedef struct {
    BaseResponse baseResponse;
    int ordersSize;
    BaseResponse * orders[];
}AllOrdersResponse;  //This is the struct I use





//This is the place where I try to create the AllOrdersResponse
else if (responseHolder->response_type() == pit::orders::rp::BaseResponse_AllOrdersResponse) {
        const pit::orders::rp::AllOrdersResponse *allOrdersResp = responseHolder->response_as_AllOrdersResponse();
        auto allOrdersResponse = std::make_shared<AllOrdersResponse>();

        allOrdersResponse->baseResponse.responseTypes = TYPE_AllOrdersResponse;
        allOrdersResponse->baseResponse.status = responseHolder->status();
        allOrdersResponse->baseResponse.statusCode = responseHolder->statusCode();
        allOrdersResponse->ordersSize = allOrdersResp->orders_size();
        for (int i=0;i<allOrdersResponse->ordersSize;i++) {
            auto singleOrder = allOrdersResp->orders()->Get(i);
            std::cout<<" Single Order Type:"<<singleOrder->response_type()<<std::endl;

            allOrdersResponse->orders[i] = getOrderFromFB(singleOrder);
        }
        result = (BaseResponse*) allOrdersResponse.get();
    }

    template<class T>
    BaseResponse* MAHelper::getOrderFromFB(T* responseHolder) {
        BaseResponse  *result;
        if (responseHolder->response_type() == pit::orders::rp::BaseResponse_OrderAccepted) {
            const piramit::orders::rp::OrderAccepted *orderAcceptedResp = responseHolder->response_as_OrderAccepted();
            std::cout<<"Order Accepted Received. Token:"<<(const char*)orderAcceptedResp->order_token()->Data()<<" OrderbookId:"<<orderAcceptedResp->order_book_id()<<std::endl;
            auto orderAccepted = std::make_shared<OrderAccepted>();
            orderAccepted->orderBookId = orderAcceptedResp->order_book_id();
            orderAccepted->orderId = orderAcceptedResp->order_id();
            orderAccepted->orderToken = (const char *)orderAcceptedResp->order_token()->Data();
            orderAccepted->timestamp = orderAcceptedResp->timestamp();
            orderAccepted->preTradeQuantity = orderAcceptedResp->pre_trade_quantity();
            orderAccepted->side = getSideResult(orderAcceptedResp->side());
            orderAccepted->strategyIdentifier = (const char *)orderAcceptedResp->strategy_identifier()->Data();
            orderAccepted->strategy = getStrategyTypeResult(orderAcceptedResp->strategy());
            orderAccepted->account = (const char*)orderAcceptedResp->account()->Data();
            orderAccepted->price = orderAcceptedResp->price();
            orderAccepted->quantity = orderAcceptedResp->quantity();
            orderAccepted->passThrough = (const char *)orderAcceptedResp->pass_through()->Data();
            orderAccepted->baseResponse.responseTypes = TYPE_OrderAccepted;
            result = (BaseResponse*) orderAccepted.get();

    }
```

so when I run the above code, its strange but it gives **free() invalid pointer** error on getOrderFromFB method in  below line:

```
auto orderAccepted = std::make_shared<OrderAccepted>();
```

But  if I call the same method like below,everything work as expected:

```
  else if (responseHolder->response_type() == piramit::orders::rp::BaseResponse_OrderCanceled) {
        result = (BaseResponse*) getOrderFromFB(responseHolder);
    }
```

I'm not able to understand the difference between calling the same method with 2 different ways ,so one of them is working and other one is giving error
(Alternatively I've tried to replace **std::make_shared()** with **new OrderAccepted()**  however result is the same.

So I think its somehow related with using pointer to struct array and try to fill it, so does anyone know any solution about this

This is actually a C related problem because the structs you see above are pure C structs and we are developing this project as a C library, so other languages can use it. Only the methods we use inside the library is C++.

Comment: This isn't C so I removed the C tag. Also note: In C++, every `struct` and `class` definition is automatically a `typedef`inition so replace `typedef struct { ...  } BaseResponse;` with just `struct BaseResponse { ... };`

Comment: `std::string` should probably replace all your `const char*`, and `std::vector` your arrays.

Comment: `result = (BaseResponse*) allOrdersResponse.get();` store pointer which become dangling at end of scope (only owners are local).

Comment: Try to make a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem on our side.

Comment: This is actually a C related quesiton because the structs you see are pure c structs and we are developing this as a C sdk so other languages can use it. Only the methods we use inside the sdk is C++ so I cannot change the const char* to std string because the struct must stay as C struct

Comment: Your code is pretty unsafe all around. You should really scrap the idea of using std::shared pointer and then returning the raw-pointer it holds. Your shared pointer is deleted whenever the refcount reaches zero, and the raw pointer will be dangling from there on. It might be a compiler warning trying to tell you this, but without the exact error it is hard to tell.

Comment: Removed the `flatbuffers` tag as the problem as stated has nothing to do with it.

Comment: "_This is actually a C related quesiton because the structs you see are pure c structs and we are developing this as a C sdk so other languages can use it_" - It doesn't matter what the target audience is for your sdk. The _code_ is C++ code. I can buy that you do C style `typedef`s to make the struct working in C but everything else you show is still C++. Make a [mcve] and this should be solved quickly - and remove the C tag. This is C++ code.

Comment: Try compiling that with a C compiler. `int i;` *can* be Java code but if it is within a C++ program then obviously it is not Java code. Same here. Just because some parts of the code resembles C does not make it C code.

Comment: Since you've deduced that the problem somehow involves making a `shared_ptr` to `OrderAccepted`, here are some tips for creating a [mre]: **1)** Reduce the definition of `OrderAccepted` to `typedef struct { int price; } OrderAccepted;`. **2)** Remove the other `struct` definitions. **3)** Simplify your functions to remove now-unneeded assignments and unneeded I/O. **4)** Try a non-template function. If you can do all of that while retaining the error, you'll eliminate a lot of clutter from your question.

Comment: @tolgatanriverdi: you should probably have C++ version of those classes and do the conversion when required.

Comment: Here you can find the minimum testable project in the below link. Please run the application with 2 instances.(1 for server, 1 for client)  For server provide application argument s and for client c . Example: ./MANetworkMVPApp s   
https://drive.google.com/file/d/11XZgw9m8CZr9_jwROtD0FtVH-r20sqa1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I think the problem is about the template method I used. Can you please check that in the above link